# Linking issue with Armadillo / QtCreator / Qt 5.5 / Mac (OS X El Capitan 10.11.2)

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt-creator, armadillo

I'm facing a problem with the combination Armadillo C++ Linear Algebra library with Qt 5.5.1 (Clang 6.1 (Apple), 64 bit) in QtCreator.

The error I get is the following:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

 "_wrapper_dgels_", referenced from:
  void arma::lapack::gels<double>(char*, int*, int*, int*, double*, int*, double*, int*, double*, int*, int*) in simulation.o
 "_wrapper_dgelsd_", referenced from:
  void arma::lapack::gelsd<double>(int*, int*, int*, double*, int*, double*, int*, double*, double*, int*, double*, int*, int*, int*) in simulation.o
 "_wrapper_dgesv_", referenced from:
  void arma::lapack::gesv<double>(int*, int*, double*, int*, int*, double*, int*, int*) in simulation.o
 "_wrapper_dgesvx_", referenced from:
  void arma::lapack::gesvx<double>(char*, char*, int*, int*, double*, int*, double*, int*, int*, char*, double*, double*, double*, int*, double*, int*, double*, double*, double*, double*, int*, int*) in simulation.o
 "_wrapper_ilaenv_", referenced from:
  arma::lapack::laenv(int*, char*, char*, int*, int*, int*, int*) in simulation.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [shpeck.app/Contents/MacOS/shpeck] Error 1
```

Naturally, I've already tried some workarounds:

1) Checking if Armadillo was being correctly imported and could be used (AT ALL). Yes, it is correctly imported and could be used, I found out  that the problem is in this line:

```
solver = solve(jacobian,residualResults);
```

When I comment this line out the code works properly. For some reason the method is not recognized.

Comment: Add `-larmadillo` to the compile command. For example: `g++ blah.cpp -o blah -O2 -larmadillo`. Otherwise read the relevant [FAQ](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html#linking).

Comment: Yeah, that solved.. the interesting part was that I was able to instantiate and use different methods of armadillo... so, I thought the whole library would be included.. weird.. I probably has missed sth on the way.. thanks anyway!